# NHibernate, AutoFac, how to use a container instead of the default one with .core

Tags: .net, nhibernate, containers, autofac

In this way, it registers the required objects.

```
services.AddSingleton<NHibernate.ISessionFactory>(

NHibernateSessionProvider.NHibernateSessionFactory(Configuration));
        services.AddScoped<NHibernate.ISession>(factory =>
            factory
                .GetServices<NHibernate.ISessionFactory>()
                .First()
                .OpenSession()
        );
```

I would like to use autoFac and move configurations to a separate class.

```
    public class AutoFacModule : Module
    {
    private static IContainer _container;

    public delegate ISession SessionDelegate(IConfiguration configuration);

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
                         builder.RegisterType.......
    }
}
}
```

But I do not know how. I am trying to change the class from static to normal etc. Help. This is what my ISessionFactory factory looks like

```
    public static class NHibernateSessionProvider
     {
       public static ISessionFactory 
          NHibernateSessionFactory(IConfiguration configuration)
     {          
        return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012
                .ConnectionString(configuration
                .GetConnectionString("connectionString"))
                .ShowSql())


            // Mapping our entity
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                .AddFromAssemblyOf<TaskToDoItem>())

            // Create your schema at runtime.
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)
                .Create(true, true))
            .BuildConfiguration()
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
   }
```

EDIT:
I have read that it is not good practice to open the session globally and maintain it, right?

Answer (score 0):

I typically scope my sessions on a per-request basis. This assumes a web-based app, however. You certainly want to avoid holding sessions longer than is necessary.

I use a `SessionProvider` that looks like this (edited for brevity):

```
public static class SessionProvider
{
    private static readonly Lazy<ISessionFactory> _sessionFactory = new Lazy<ISessionFactory>(CreateSessionFactory);

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory => _sessionFactory.Value;

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }

    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        return 
            Fluently
                .Configure(Config)
                .Mappings()
                .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

I then register `ISession` as a per-request scoped service, usually with a factory method:

```
container.Register(c => SessionProvider.OpenSession(), Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

I don't register my `SessionFactory` with my IoC container. I rely on it's static nature and inherent thread-safety.

I'm not familiar with AutoFac, however I would imagine you should be able to do something like:

```
builder.Register(c => SessionProvider.OpenSession()).InstancePerRequest();
```